# Flask, jinja, sqlalchemy. Скачивание png файла пользователем

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог скачивать файлы по нажатию кнопки?
Имеется файл таблицы базы данных:

```
    import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import orm

from .db_session import SqlAlchemyBase
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin


class Stuffs(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Stuffs'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                           primary_key=True,
                           autoincrement=True)
    title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                              nullable=False)
    pic = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                            nullable=False)
    price = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                              nullable=False)
    # Привяжем таблицу материалов к пользователям (Создаём внешний ключ)
    user_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("Users.id"))
    user = orm.relationship("User")

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
```

Страница index выглядит следующим образом:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main_content %}
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center ">
        <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">
            {% for item in stuffs %}
            <div class="col" style="flex-basis: 25%">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm p-1 border bg-light rounded">
                    <div style="height: 170px;" class="text-center">
                        <br/>
                        <img style="height: 170px;" src="/static/images/{{ item.pic }}"
                             class="border border-light rounded img-fluid" alt="{{ item.title }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title pricing-card-title">{{ item.title }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4" style="font-weight: bold">$ {{ item.price }}</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for item in image %}
            <div class="col" style="flex-basis: 25%">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm p-1 border bg-light rounded">
                    <div style="height: 170px;" class="text-center">
                        <img style="height: 170px;" src="{{ item.path }}" class="border border-light rounded img-fluid"
                             alt="{{ item.id }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title pricing-card-title">{{ item.name }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4" style="font-weight: bold">$ {{ item.price }}</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Пробовал сделать на подобии этого декоратора из другого кода:

```
@app.route('/download/<int:id>')
@login_required
def item_download(id):
    cur_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y в %H:%M:%S')
    db_sess = db_session.create_session()
    item = db_sess.query(Book).get(id)
    file_name = item.pdf
    full_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_PDF'])
    order = Order(
        user=current_user.get_id(),
        books=item.id,
        date=cur_date
    )
    db_sess.add(order)
    db_sess.commit()
    return send_from_directory(full_path, file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Но не смог подогнать этот фрагмент под свою таблицу, постоянно выдаёт различные ошибки по поводу типа файла

```
order = Order(
        user=current_user.get_id(),
        books=item.id,
        date=cur_date
    )
```